# Test componentWillUnmount() removes a class from body

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have React component with the following code:

```
  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.body.classList.remove('isPreloaded')
  }
```

I have `body` tag with `isPreloaded` class, Preloader HTML and styles for it initially in index.html (as critical things). When the app is loaded, Preloader component is rendered into body (nothing changes for the user). And when data arrives from server, Preloader is removed. Of course I have to remove `isPreloaded` class, as it makes body unscrollable.

The above description is not directly connected to my question, but I decided to add it to prevent comments like "This is bad practice" or similar.

So I want to test this behavior. To ensure this works as expected I have to render this component inside `<body>` with class `isPreloaded` and save it in a variable, let it be `container`. Then I have to check that this class exists in `container`. And in the second test I have to unmount the component from container and check that the class disappeared.

This is approximately what I want to achieve:

```
describe('<Preloader />', () => {
  const container = mount(<body className='isPreloaded'><Preloader /></body>)

  it('should be rendered with `isPreloaded` class', () => {
    expect(container.find('isPreloaded').length).toBe(1)
  })

  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(container).childNode)

  it('should remove `isPreloaded` class from body when unmounted', () => {
    expect(container.find('.isPreloaded').length).toBe(0)
  })
})
```

But it doesn't work. The first assertion returns 0 instead of 1 and therefore fails. The second one throws the following error:

`Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.`

Comment: react version??

Comment: @Codesingh 15.4.1

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(container).childNode)` is a asynchronous function so you should do this :-

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(container).childNode)
}, 3000
```

you can also add listener to componentWillUnmount().

for `it` issue use this:

```
let {TestUtils} = React.addons;
this.container = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<body       className='isPreloaded'><Preloader /></body>)
this.renderedDOM = () => React.findDOMNode(this.container);

it('should be rendered with `isPreloaded` class', () => {
    expect(this.renderedDOM().children.length).toEqual(1);
  })
```

Comment: Perhaps using `setImmediate` (or `process.nextTick`) once or twice is enough. `setImmediate(_ => setImmediate(func))` will run `func` two main loop cycles after invocation. By then, callbacks wil probably have ran. No need to wait 3 seconds

Comment: Yes these are alternatives.

Comment: @Codesingh Thanks for the answer. Could you please provide the full example? Also, what about the first `it` block returning 0? How do I do this?